# Transpose single column after NA to multiple columns with R

Tags: r

I would like to transpose a single column to multiple columns after two NA's. I have tried to transpose at every nth row, but there is no pattern.

Example:

```
x<-data.frame(col1=c('A','F',1,15,'','','A','Z','$35','P',2,'','','B','ER',3,'P',56,'YT65','','','B','AZ','$5','PO',28,'',''))
```

What I am hoping to accomplish is:

| col1 | col 2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | F | 1 | 15 |  |  |
| A | Z | $35 | P | 2 |  |
| B | ER | 3 | P | 56 | YT65 |
| B | AZ | $5 | PO | 28 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little convoluted, but you could do:

```r
z <- lapply(split(x$col1, cumsum(!nzchar(x$col1)) %/% 2), function(x) { 
  if(!nzchar(x[1])) x[-1] else x
})

z <- do.call(rbind, lapply(z, function(x) {
  c(x, rep('', max(lengths(z)) - length(x)))
  }))

as.data.frame(z[rowSums(z == '') != ncol(z), colSums(z == '') != nrow(z)])
#>   V1 V2  V3 V4 V5   V6
#> 0  A  F   1 15        
#> 1  A  Z $35  P  2     
#> 2  B ER   3  P 56 YT65
#> 3  B AZ  $5 PO 28
```

Comment: This is perfect. You are a life saver! I've literally been trying to solve this for 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "F", 1, 15, "", "", 
                         "A", "Z", "$35", "P", 2, "", "", 
                         "B", "ER", 3, "P", 56, "YT65", "", "", 
                         "B", "AZ", "$5", "PO", 28, "", ""))

df |> 
  mutate(group = cumsum(col1 == "")) |> 
  filter(col1 != "") |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  mutate(col = row_number()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = col1) |> 
  select(-group)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`  
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 A     F     1     15    <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2 A     Z     $35   P     2     <NA> 
#> 3 B     ER    3     P     56    YT65 
#> 4 B     AZ    $5    PO    28    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>